# Merging adjustment layers with each layer below individually

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

How can I apply and merge one adjustment layer to each layer below it separately? (Each individual layer should be merged with the adjustment layer, but still be it's *own* layer)

- I don't want to merge all the layers.
- I don't want to create a smart object.
- I don't want to copy the adjustments to each layer and merge them individually.

Why I need it:  I am creating an illustration of a room, each layer is a piece of furniture, I want to change the allover light and I want to paint on on the layers using the color picker.

[image]

Comment: Say I have a photoshop File with 100 layers.  And say I created 3 adjustment layers on top of those 100 layers to get the adjustments that i want for those layers.   I'm happy with the adjustments but Then I NEED to merge those 3 adjustment layers to ALL those 100 layers.   Is there a way to easily permanently apply the adjustments to each of those layers without having to do it manually?

Comment: The problem is I cant paint on the layers if the adjustment is not merged into each layer seperately becouse the colorpicker picks the adjusted color and then I would paint with it under the adjustment.

Comment: here this guy has a similar problem just i dont need to export any layers. https://forums.adobe.com/message/4453282#4453282

Answer (score 1):

**Create an Action**

- Open the Actions Panel (Alt+F9) and Click on the 'Create new action' button:

[image: New Action Button]

- Name your action Merge Adjustments (why not eh?) and click 'Record'
- Apply your three adjustments to your topmost layer (for our purposes), but rather than using Adjustment Layers just apply successive adjustments directly to the layer by going to Image > Adjustments:

[image: Adjustment Menu]

This method also retains layer names

- Finally press Alt+[ to select the next layer down, then click the 'Stop' button at the bottom-left of the Actions Panel to finish recording

Now just press 'Play' 99 times to apply the same adjustments to your remaining layers...

Comment: @Iggy Kov  No problem... Glad I could help!

Comment: @IggyKov If you found this answer useful please vote it up. If this has answered your question, please mark it as such so it will be removed from the 'Unanswered' page. Cheers